# Adding constraints to Map View

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, constraints, mapkit

I have problem setting constraints to Map Kit View.

Here's a screenshot of my current constraints:

[image]

However, when I switch to another screen size, the MKMapView does not resize accordingly, although a label with the exact same constraints behaves as expected:

[image]

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the Xcode project:

*https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18149046/Test.zip*

Comment: I don't understand your problem or your "question". What error are you getting? What is your exact problem? What is your expected outcome and what do you actually get? Images will be helpful because your constraints look fine.

Comment: I edited the question and provided additional screenshot as you suggested. I hope it is clearer now. (And sorry for my English)

Comment: Interface Builder tells you the problem in the tree view to the left of the screen (the red arrow against the scene) but I can now see you have two conflicting constraints: You are telling the `MKMapView` to be sized vertically so that it is '259 points from the bottom of the screen' AND '0 points from the top of the TableView`. These conflict. Delete the constraint that is '259 points from the bottom of the screen'. If you are finding this difficult then I strongly urge you to read the documentation or find a tutorial.

Comment: Removing the constraint did not solve the problem. I updated the question, showing that the constraints are set correctly. Labels and Table View behave as expected with the constraints, but when I set the exact same constraints to the Map View, it goes crazy on different screen sizes.

I also included a link to the Xcode files, so you can see for yourself.

Edit: The Interface Builders tells me that I have "Misplaced views", with expected width and height being different from actual width and height.

Comment: According to those images you still have a hard-coded distance to the Bottom Layout Guide AND the TableView. This will cause a conflict on iDevices with different screen sizes. The base issue is that you need to define the height of the `MKMapView`. I'll write an answer with examples in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't open your Storyboard - it just gave me the spinning beachball of death so I wrote my own. As usual with Autolayout, there are multiple ways to achieve the end result but each solves the fundamental problem which is:

1. Neither an `MKMapView` nor a `UITableView` have an intrinsic size (labels do have an intrinsic size).
2. You need to specify a `height` for the `MKMapView` in order to fix the `y position` and `height` of the `UITableView` AND the `MKMapView`

So I show two ways of doing this.

Method 1 (my preferred method : Use a `UIStackView`):

1. Embed the `MKMapView` and `UITableView` within a Vertical `UIStackView`
2. Pin the `UIStackView` to the Layout Guides / Edges of your Superview
3. Set the Attributes->Distribution to `Fill Equally`

This has the advantages that you can customise the layout for different Size Classes directly within IB and there are no "magic" numbers so it works for all Size Classes with no changes

[image: Example 1: Main Layout Window]

[image: Example 1: StackView Utility Window Settings]

Method 2 (hardcode a height into a container view for the `MKMapView`):

1. Add a `UIView` and place the `MKMapView` within it
2. Set the `MKMapView` Autoresizing springs in the Size Inspector to solid red for the arrows (and unblock the I-Bars if set); see image below
3. Set a height for the `UIView` containing the `MKMapView`; in my example I hard-code `300`
4. Pin the `UIView` containing the `MKMapView` to the Leading, Trailing, Top Layout Guides / Superview Edges
5. Pin the `UIView` containing the `MKMapView` to the Top of the `UITableView`
6. Pin the `UITableView` to the Leading, Trailing, Bottom Layout Guides / Superview Edges

[image: Example 2: Main Layout Window]
[image: Example 2: MKMapView Size Inspector]

This has the dis-advantage that you may need to adjust the `MKMapView` height constraint depending on different size iDevices (although you may be able to update the constraint to be a proportion of the `SuperView`; I haven't checked)

In both my examples I am giving a `height` to the `MKMapView` which then defines the `y position` and `height` of the `UITableView`.

If you are looking for a tutorial that explains Autolayout in detail (if the documentation doesn't make everything clear) then I recommend `Developing iOS 9 Apps with Swift` on `iTunesU` but there are large numbers on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you! So I understand, that Map View and Labels are not expected to behave the same way even when they have the same constraints applied. I wasn't aware of the Stack View feature, it makes this so much easier! I really appreciate your help.